# What proportion of Christians worldwide identify as Christian for social/cultural reasons rather than religious conviction?

Tags: catholicism, atheism, demographics

In [2007 survey](http://www.catholicculture.org/news/features/index.cfm?recnum=48547) showed that only half of the French who identify themselves as Catholics believed in God.

> Some respondents indicated that for them, Catholicism involves a social or cultural identity rather than a religious commitment.

I was wondering whether global figures were known, i.e. do we know how large globally is the share of Christians (alternatively of Catholics) which believe in God?

Answer (score 1):

**What proportion of Christians worldwide identify as Christian for social/cultural reasons rather than religious conviction?**

It would be difficult to come up with a specific percentage.

Those who call themselves Christian for financial or social advantage usually do so when Christianity is an ascendency. Like when Christianity was made official in the Roman empire in the fourth century and in America during the 19th and 20th centuries. In Europe during the middle ages you may have seen some pretend Christians not necessarily for advantage but survival because there would be penalties for trying to live as a non-Christian.

There have always been Christians (or any other religion) that are of that religion for what might be called familial inertial reasons. Legacy or heritage members of a religion would be hard to distinguish until that religion became persecuted and they took advantage of the opportunity to leave the religion.

The reaction of Christians to a world hostile to them was described by Jesus;

> Luke 9:26  For whosoever shall be ashamed of me and of my words, of
>   him shall the Son of man be ashamed, when he shall come in his own
>   glory, and in his Father's, and of the holy angels.

Whatever the percentage is today it would be shrinking because it is starting to become a disadvantage to be a Christian.

Comment: This is a good comment, but it doesn't appear to meet the criteria for an answer.

Comment: The question is clarified as asking about "the proportion of Christians who [claim to] believe in God." This gives a more general answer; if the question were merely what the title says, it would be too broad.